# TextBox or Upload File losing value on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, textbox, postback

I have a user control that will render a textbox or file upload.
  I have a web page in which im rendering this user control + a button that will submit the form.
  on code behind.whem im trying to get the value of my textbox im getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", this is because im losing my user control on post back, any idea how can i solve this ?
thanks alot

**EDIT:** `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ResourceEditorUpdatePanel" runat="server" />` and at run time am creating my user control and adding to the updatepanel/panel controls

Comment: you have to recreate dynamic controls...

Comment: when i recreate them i will have an empty textbox,i will lose the ones that the user filled

Comment: can you provide some code? I'm interested in the way you are setting IDs of the dynamic controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i have to do was to set

> EnableViewState

Value =true while creating the user control, and in my user control i forgot to put the

> ensureChildcontrols() method on OnLoad()

Answer (score 0):

use updatepanel of AJAX, i hope i will reduce most of problem.